# Как заполнить ComboBox из массива?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

У меня есть большой стринговый массив и нужно по нему заполнить ComboBox в ListBox можно сделать так `listBox.Items.AddRange(StringArray);` А как это сделать в ComboBox?

Comment: А массив обязательно использовать? Для таких целей , на мой взгляд, удобнее использовать List<T>

Answer (score 3):

Есть `ComboBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange` , но на мой взгляд для таких целей лучше использовать списки.

Comment: А заполнение ComboBox по списку так же?

Comment: Мне VS говорит, что ComboBox не содержит определения для ObjectCollection...

Answer (score 0):

В ComboBox элементы из массива можно добавить так:

```
foreach(var item in array)
{
    ComboBox.Items.Add(item);
}
```

`foreach` пройдет по каждому элементу массива и выполнит нужный код. Код же каждый элемент по отдельности добавит в коллекцию итемов комбо бокса

PS: Вместо массива можно точно таким же образом подставлять список